# Nitobi Grid remove the add row and remove row buttons

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, gridview

I am using the Nitobi Grid in my php website. I would like to remove the buttons 
like add row and remove row on the grid toolbar. I cant remove the whole toolbar as i need the bar for paginating.
    Please let me know if there is any way to remove these buttons. Any ideas are appreciated.